# Atomically establish relation between records

Tags: sql, atomic, consistency

I'm developing an e-commerce website that delivers unique digital products (e.g. 40-digit codes). These digital products are stored as rows in a `stock` table. When an order is placed, *one unique digital product* should be assigned to the order.

Currently, I'm selecting the oldest product (in a first-in first-out manner), doing some business logic (sending an e-mail to the customer, etc.) and deleting the record from the stock table. The problem is that this operation is *not atomic*. E.g. if two orders are placed at the same time, the same code is selected, e-mailed to the customer, and deleted (though the second delete will fail, ofcourse). This leaves the database in an inconsistent state (from a business perspective), because the same unique digital product is assigned to two orders.

**How to establish a link between a digital product from table `stock` and an order from table `order` in a consistent/atomic fashion?**

PS. I'm currently using MySQL (MyISAM), but I'm not too fond of the lack of referential integrity. I plan on moving to either InnoDB or PostgreSQL in the near future. Therefore, I'd prefer a technology-independent answer.

Comment: Are you using transactions or are you auto committing each statement?

Comment: Currently autocommitting each statement. Using transactions was the first thing that came to my mind, but even transactions wont prevent the same digital product from being selected twice, afaik..

Comment: I don't know how you retrieve the id, but could you not implement some kind of semaphore so that only one id is handled at the time? I.e. `create table semaphore ( ts timestamp not null )` Now, every transaction can start with: `update semaphore set ts = now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the Stock table.  Call it `Allocated` or somesuch.  Its values will be 0 (not allocated) or 1 (is allocated).  0 is the default.  Once you read a row from `Stock` to add to a customer's order you will have the primary key, I'd assume.  Then you

```
update Stock
set Allocated = 1
where Stock.PrimaryKey = <the value you just read>
and Stock.Allocated = 0;
```

This one statement *is* atomic by definition, unless you have some pathologic isolation level set.

If that fails someone else has called "dibs" on that stock item.  Loop back to the "read oldest stock item" step.  Of course you only want to read items `where Allocated = 0`. Repeat as often as needed, or you run out of stock items.

If your process fails catestrophically at some subsequent step you may end up with some orphaned stock items i.e. have `Allocated = 1` but no email has ever been sent.

You would be better off having a transaction around all these steps since you expect them all to succeed or all rollback.